# Is it possible to sort numbers in Power BI when data is fetched directly from the server?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, powerbi-desktop

the order of numbers or data manipulation in general is very easy when the data is imported, but in a direct connection with analisys services I cannot find the solution, since all operations with the data are blocked when having a direct connection.

[image]

Example of how the visual object that contains the data looks like (numbers but takes them as a string)

Comment: Is a bad design in analisys services

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to go into Visual Studio and change Data type (click the column, Properties window, under Basic) to Whole number or Decimal.